# SQL Server 2012 : attach two rows of data to one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

SQL Server stored procedure I am using to get my current dataset:

```
SELECT 
    DcProd.Title, 
    DcProd.Summary, 
    DcProd.Product, 
    EfProd.ProductStatus, 
    EfProd.ViewOnlyLicenses, 
    EfProd.FullLicenses, 
    DcProd.ProductType, 
    DcProd.Advertise, 
    EfProd.CustomerAccount_Id, 
    DcRelation.component_property_name, 
    DcRelation.child_item_id,  
    DcRelation.child_item_additional_info, 
    DcPageRelation.url_name_    
FROM 
    [MC_Sitefinity].[dbo].[mastercontrolproducts_mastercontrolproduct] AS DcProd
LEFT JOIN 
    [MasterControlSitefinity].[dbo].[ProductLicense] AS EfProd ON DcProd.Product = EfProd.Product_Id  --matching dynamic content (Dc) products to Entity Framework (Ef) products
LEFT JOIN 
    [MC_Sitefinity].[dbo].[sf_dynamic_content] AS DcStatus ON DcProd.base_id = DcStatus.base_id -- show only published and visible. 
LEFT JOIN 
    [MC_Sitefinity].[dbo].[sf_content_link] AS DcRelation ON DcStatus.original_content_id = DcRelation.parent_item_id --Gets related items for image and page url
LEFT JOIN 
    [MC_Sitefinity].[dbo].[sf_page_node] AS DcPageRelation ON DcRelation.child_item_id = DcPageRelation.id --gets page url for query
WHERE
    EfProd.CustomerAccount_Id = 'someid00184' 
    AND DcStatus.visible = 1 
    AND DcStatus.approval_workflow_state_ = 'Published'
ORDER BY
    ProductType
```

Here is the example data set returned:

[http://1drv.ms/1MKjAsU](http://1drv.ms/1MKjAsU/) (OneDrive excel spreadsheet)

Or if you prefer: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=26D02110D254A382!317&authkey=!ACe_T3VVcf_pzY4&ithint=file%2cxlsx

Desired result (open to ideas not set in stone):
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=26D02110D254A382!320&authkey=!ANxIz3ULXZ9rZvE&ithint=file%2cxlsx

This is not all the data returned but some of the key records I am trying to show.

You will notice we have multiple tables. What is happening is for each record on the left there are sometimes two records on the right causing duplicated rows.

What I would like if possible is (looking at last two rows) if we could combine **child_item_additional_info** and **url_name_** on one line instead of two. As for the data in the **component_property_name** it could just be deleted or combined with a pipe (|) or whatever is recommended.

I have looked at cases, pivot tables, but I just am a little green when it comes to SQL and unsure how to do this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've got a flaw in logic.  Either your data or your join doesn't represent the reality you believe exists.  Your join says that DcPageRelation is already related to DcRelation directly.  If you're getting two rows with that join, it's because DcRelation has two rows, and DcPageRelation is only related to one of them.  In other words, you wrote that `DcRelation.child_item_id = DcPageRelation.id`, and now you're saying that sometimes that's not true.  Since that's your only join condition, well, either your logic or the code's logic are wrong.  Or the data is bad.

Comment: DcRelation has two rows, one that is for the image and one that is for the page. DcPageRelation only relates to the page. so do I need a conditional statement in there somehow? thank you again, starting to understand my issue better.

Comment: Can you post what you want the expected results to look like?

Comment: modified my original post with desired look however here is the link: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=26D02110D254A382!320&authkey=!ANxIz3ULXZ9rZvE&ithint=file%2cxlsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the help, I just wanted to post how I solved this problem. I was able to do it with a second select statement.

```
SELECT 
        DcProd.Title,
        EfProd.Name, 
        DcProd.Summary, 
        DcProd.Product, 
        EfProd.ProductStatus, 
        EfProd.ViewOnlyLicenses, 
        EfProd.FullLicenses,
        DcProd.Advertise, 
        EfProd.CustomerAccount_Id, 
        DcPageRelation.url_name_,
    CASE 
        WHEN DcProd.ProductType = 1 THEN 'Module'
        WHEN DcProd.ProductType = 2 THEN 'Portal Add-On'
        WHEN DcProd.ProductType = 3 THEN 'Language'
        WHEN DcProd.ProductType = 4 THEN 'Jumpstart'
        WHEN DcProd.ProductType = 5 THEN 'Documents Connector'
        WHEN DcProd.ProductType = 6 THEN 'Documents Add-On'
        WHEN DcProd.ProductType = 7 THEN 'Express'
        WHEN DcProd.ProductType = 8 THEN 'Process Add-On'
        WHEN DcProd.ProductType = 9 THEN 'Process Solution'
        WHEN DcProd.ProductType = 10 THEN 'Training Add-On'
        ELSE null END AS ProdType,
        (SELECT DcRelation2.child_item_additional_info
        FROM [MC_Sitefinity].[dbo].[sf_dynamic_content] AS DcStatus2 
        LEFT JOIN 
        [MC_Sitefinity].[dbo].[sf_content_link] AS DcRelation2 ON DcStatus2.original_content_id = DcRelation2.parent_item_id AND DcRelation2.component_property_name='Image'
        WHERE DcProd.base_id= DcStatus2.base_id) as theimage

    FROM 
        [MC_Sitefinity].[dbo].[mastercontrolproducts_mastercontrolproduct] AS DcProd  
    LEFT JOIN 
        [MasterControlSitefinity].[dbo].[ProductLicense] AS EfProd ON DcProd.Product = EfProd.Product_Id 
        AND EfProd.CustomerAccount_Id = @CustomerId  --matching dynamic content (Dc) products to Entity Framework (Ef) products
    LEFT JOIN 
        [MC_Sitefinity].[dbo].[sf_dynamic_content] AS DcStatus ON DcProd.base_id = DcStatus.base_id -- show only published and visible. 
    LEFT JOIN 
        [MC_Sitefinity].[dbo].[sf_content_link] AS DcRelation ON DcStatus.original_content_id = DcRelation.parent_item_id 
        AND DcRelation.component_property_name = 'ProductPageUrl' --Gets related items for page url
    LEFT JOIN
        [MC_Sitefinity].[dbo].[sf_page_node] AS DcPageRelation ON DcRelation.child_item_id = DcPageRelation.id --gets page url for query
    WHERE
        DcStatus.visible = 1 
        AND DcStatus.approval_workflow_state_ = 'Published'
    ORDER BY
        ProdType
```